# Javascript and only one Checkbox - undefined

Tags: javascript, html, forms, checkbox

```
for (i = 0; i < document.checks.user.length; i++) //for all check boxes
{
    if (document.checks.user[i].checked == true )
    {
        document.checks.submit();
        return 0;
    }
}

<body>
<form action="" method=POST name="checks" ID="Form2">
  I have a bike:
  <input type="checkbox" name="user" value="Bike" ID="Checkbox1">
  <br>
  <br>
</form>
<input type="button" value="Delete" 
    class="btn" onclick="sub_delete()" 
    onmouseover="hov(this, 'btn btnhov')" onmouseout="hov(this, 'btn')" 
    id="Button1" name="Button1" 
/>
</body>
```

as you probably already know when there is only one check box left document.checks.user.length = undefined. Whats the most efficient way to make sure that when there is only one check box, it will be deleted. I was thinking just thinking to add it as a seperate if statement before the if statement here.....any suggesstions.

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you give all your checkboxes the same name? That doesn't make much sense.

Comment: because then you can process them as an array when it is submitted to something like php... makes perfect sense...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a loop control variable, and set it to 1 if length is undefined...

```
var len = document.checks.user.length;
if(len == undefined) len = 1;
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) //for all check boxes
```

Best regards...

Comment: This is what I am looking for. However, I realized when there is only one element left, the if statement I have will not work when there is only 1 element. i.e -> if (document.checks.user[0].checked == true )

Comment: I believe it no longer sees user as an array....? I'll put the document.checks.submit(); in this loop control.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (document.getElementById('Checkbox1').checked) { /* do something */ }
```

if you want to loop a bunch of checkboxes, you could loop the input fields of your form, like:

```
var formNodes  = document.checks.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (var i=0;i<formNodes.length;i++) {
   /* do something with the name/value/id or checked-state of formNodes[i] */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(document.checks.user[0]) {
  //it's an array
}
else {
  //it's a single element
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is somewhat confusing, since your javascript would obviously have to be inside a function called 'sub_delete' to be any use... someone with the mighty power to edit questions might improve the question by making that clearer...

So the first issue you have to get around is the fact that for single checkbox, with a given name 'user', is not an array, and therefore has no defined length, but also if you try and access it as an array.. things get confused.. a full rewrite of your javascript function might look like this:

```
    function sub_delete{
        if (typeof document.checks.user.length === 'undefined') {
   /*then there is just one checkbox with the name 'user' no array*/
        if (document.checks.user.checked == true )
                            {
                                document.checks.submit();
                                return 0;
                            }   
    }else{
  /*then there is several checkboxs with the name 'user' making an array*/
        for(var i = 0, max = document.checks.user.length; i < max; i++){
            if (document.checks.user[i].checked == true )
                            {
                                document.checks.submit();
                                return 0;
                            }

        }
    }
    }//sub_delete end
```

HTH,
-FT

Answer (score 1):

I too face the same proble with total of 5 checkboxes out of which 4 are disabled and 1 is enabled. Now the checkboxId.length is undefined, so the only option I could think of is if(checkboxId.length ==undefined ){checkboxId.checked=true & submith the form}.

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple, just create a hidden input tag with the name same as the existing checkbox input tag.

For example:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="user" value="Bike" ID="Checkbox1">
<input type="hidden" name="user" value=""/>
```

Answer (score -1):

I'd probably iterate across document.checks.elements, looking for .type == 'checkbox'.

Answer (score -2):

jQuery is your friend:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").attr('checked', false);
```

(... if jQuery is available to you?)

Comment: checks is the name of the <form>, user is the name of the checkbox.

Comment: Ugh, recommending a massive framework for the simplest of tasks.

Comment: Heh - yeah, I take your point. I guess I'm just a bit wowed by jQuery of late: it's solved *so* many of my browser-specific headaches! :-)