# Can Form Submissions Be Handled Completely With PHP or Do I Need Other Technologies?

Tags: php, checkbox

I have a form which allow users to choose the type of permit they wish to apply for. There are 3 types of permit class and 8 categories of permit type.

Please take a look at this screenshot for better understanding: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRC9O.jpg

For the classes, users can only choose 1. but for the categories users can apply multiple or single.

Users can choose 2 categories but 0 classes. Likewise users can choose 1 class and 0 categories. But user must at least choose something out of the 11 options.

Eg. User apply for Class 1 only OR User apply for CAT 2TT and CAT 3PG.

The coding to my form:

```
  <div class="contents">
  <form id="applicationoptions" method="post" action="s_apply_now.php">
  <div id="optionshead">Class :</div>
      <div id="classoptions">
          <input type="radio" name="class" value="1" /> Class 1 Permit             &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <input type="radio" name="class" value="2" /> Class 2 Permit &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <input type="radio" name="class" value="3" /> Class 3 Permit
      </div>
  <div id="optionshead2">Categories :</div>
      <div id="catoptions">
          <input type="checkbox" name="cat" value="1" /> CAT 2PG &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <input type="checkbox" name="cat" value="2" /> CAT 1OR &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <input type="checkbox" name="cat" value="3" /> CAT 2TT <br/><br/>
          <input type="checkbox" name="cat" value="4" /> CAT 3PG &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <input type="checkbox" name="cat" value="5" /> CAT 2OR &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <input type="checkbox" name="cat" value="6" /> CAT 3TT <br/><br/>
          <input type="checkbox" name="cat" value="7" /> CAT 4PG &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <input type="checkbox" name="cat" value="8" /> CAT 3OR
      </div>
  <div class="applynext">
 <input class="applynextbutton" type="submit" name="applynextbutton" value="PROCEED" />
 </div>
  </form>
  </div>
```

After user checked their selection, the system will then separate the selections and store them in the database.

The database schema:
permit (PID, EID, PTYPE, STATUS, MID, HRID)

If user did not choose anything, the system will alert them and ask them to choose something

If user choose more than 2 class, the system will warn alert them to choose only 1 class.

What do you guys think? Is PHP able to allow me to accomplish these intentions?

P.S.: Please tell me how can I make spaces without using too many `&npsb;`. Is there a way to change the radio button to checkbox and disable the multiple selection?

Guys...I have a problem...how do I in php to retrieve data from checkbox?? any example??
i tried array[] it but can't seem to work..

Comment: PHP is a fully Turing complete language. Yes, it will allow you to express this in code.

Comment: Why do people vote me down but do not tell me what is wrong?? confused

Comment: @deceze hmm do i need to use any other language to make this work?

Comment: The downvote is most likely because you didn't tell us what you tried or what research you've done already. You're simply asking if you can do X, which is very basic and might be answerable with some research on your part. I didn't downvote you, but that's likely part of why others did. The best questions on SO show you've done research, as per the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: No. You build a form using PHP. User fills in form and submits it. You check the data using PHP and output errors or another form or whatever is necessary. Rinse, repeat until the data is valid, then insert it into the database.

Comment: @jmort253 understood...i will learnt that for future post

Comment: I made your question title more detailed, this will hopefully make the question appear more specific.

Comment: @jmort253 Thanks...I think i really need to think of the qns properly before asking...but i did several search on google and here...i cant't find a way to make checkbox disable multiple selection.

Comment: So your specific question is how to select only a single checkbox of multiple? That's not what checkboxen are for. Checkboxen == multiple choice, **radio buttons** == single choice.

Comment: Checkboxes are designed for multiple selection. For single selection, you'll need radio buttons.

Comment: @deceze hmm if that is the only way...how do i allow users to deselect a radio button? for example if I click on Class 1 then i realise i do not want to apply for a class permit but i can't deselect.

Comment: Well, you only have these two tools. Finding a solution using the available tools is your job as a programmer. :o) Perhaps it would make sense for you to break the form into multiple steps. 1) Choose type, 2) depending on the chosen type, choose permit... or whatever.

Comment: Found a way to deselect radio button.

Comment: Really, Radio buttons shouldn't be deselectable. You could go with 3 buttons, "Male, Female, Unspecified" and default the radio button to being "Unspecified". If someone doesn't want to select one of the two options, they select whatever your "unspecified" option is. Look at how some "reputable" sites handle this same problem. You're definitely not doing something that no one on the Internet has never ever done before. Look at the reputable sites (emphasize reputable) to determine what the UI/flow should look like. :)

Comment: `<input type="radio" name="class" value="0" /> No permit`

Comment: @jmort253 I will take note of what you say...i will try to figure another way

Comment: Like I said, just create an extra option called, "none". It will fit your workflow and not confuse anyone by changing the behavior of the Web or their expectations of how radio buttons behave. My concern is just to help you avoid confusing people :)  Good luck!

Comment: @jmort253 thanks...if i use none, for the condition statement, i should say `if ($_POST['class'] == none) { //do nothing } elseif ($_POST['class'] == 1) { //store data into database }......` right?

Comment: `if($_POST['class'] == 1) { /*store in the db*/ }`.  No need for the `//do nothing part` as by omitting the == none part, you imply that you want to do nothing for that condition. However, what you proposed would also work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes PHP will work.  You can get the necessary data posted via the $_POST collection, and communicate with whatever database you're using to store them.

For spacing, I suggest [learning CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp) and avoid adding lots of non-breaking spaces.

As far as handling the checkbox values, it looks like you want to allow the user to select multiple values corresponding to one name (class, and cat).  As you have it, PHP will just end up with the last value they selected.  You can modify the name of your form inputs to cause PHP to treat them like an array on the backend.  Then when you grab $_POST['class'] you will get an array.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="class[]" value="1" /> First class
<input type="checkbox" name="class[]" value="2" /> Second class
```

If both of those are checked by the user, you would see this in PHP

```
$classes = $_POST['class'];
// array(1, 2)
```

If they only checked one, you would have just one element in the array.

You can even make it an associative array if having keys in your array make it easier to handle the data:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="class[first]" value="1" /> First class
<input type="checkbox" name="class[second]" value="2" /> Second class
```

and in PHP

```
$classes = $_POST['class'];
// array('first'=>1, 'second'=>2)
```

Comment: thanks...hmm...how do i separate the array results to individual variable? i know i need a loop right?

Comment: hmm can i use list() and split() to split the results individually?

Comment: sure, you can loop over the variable you pulled off of $_POST if it's an array.  I'd recommend that over using list().  You shouldn't need to split any of the values, they'll each be their own entry in the array.

Comment: hmm...hi can i ask if i just run `echo $classes;` the result on the webpage would just be the word 'Array' right?

Comment: hmmu were saying that the  they'll each be their own entry in the array...but how do i loop it for example  if it is array(1,2) i need to get it like `$permit1=1; $permit2=2;`? because the length of the array would not be known how can i loop it so that i would have just nice the number of variable to the number of result? Thanks for guidance

Answer (score 1):

No problem for PHP, it laughs doing this and gets lazy. But without jokes: absolute no problem. You can use as much if and else statements as you want (within the maximum execution time, but let's not make it more difficult than is already is).

As for your checkbox issue, as suggested, as you made it now is the right way. You can however use a javascript function to 'hack' the standard checkbox function to radio-like. See http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t80854-how-to-allow-only-one-checkbox-to-be-checked-in-a-group-of-checkboxes.html and/or [Javascript and only one Checkbox - undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534657/javascript-and-only-one-checkbox-undefined) for information about that.

You also can make the radio look better, look here for more information about that http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/ You can also add a empty radio with the label 'Nothing' to select, and let this one standard be selected. This will fix your problem to - many roads lead to Rome. :)

As for the final space problem, use proper make-up.

```
<div style="width: 250px;">a button</div>
<div style="width: 250px; float: right;">a second button</div>
```

for exampe. You can also use a somewhat older table structure:

```
<table><tr><td width="250">a button</td><td width="250">a second button</td></tr></table>
```

where table is the table, tr a row and td a cell.

Comment: oh yah i tollay forgotten about using a table...because i heard if you have div tags in your table it would not work at all...is that true?

Comment: No, not true. But be sure to put them in `<table><tr><td><div>`here `</div></td></tr></table>`. You can put a `<div>` around a `<table><tr><td>`too! `</td></tr></table></div>`, so you have full flexibility.