# How to check that at least one checkbox is checked in multiple checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, checkbox

In my form so many checkboxes are used. I want to check that at least one checkbox is checked.

```
<div id="sun">
    <li><?php echo $this->__("SUN");?> </li>
    <li><input class="allday" type="checkbox" name="availableday[Sunday][9-12]" value="9AM - 12AM"></li>
    <li><input class="allday" type="checkbox" name="availableday[Sunday][12-6]" value="12PM - 6PM"></li>
    <li><input class="allday" type="checkbox" name="availableday[Sunday][6-9]" value="6PM - 9PM"></li>
</div>
<div id="mon">
    <li><?php echo $this->__("MON");?> </li>
    <li><input class="allday" type="checkbox" name="availableday[Monday][9-12]" value="9AM - 12AM"></li>
    <li><input class="allday" type="checkbox" name="availableday[Monday][12-6]" value="12PM - 6PM"></li>
    <li><input class="allday" type="checkbox" name="availableday[Monday][6-9]" value="6PM - 9PM"></li>
</div>
<div id="tue">
    <li><?php echo $this->__("TUE");?> </li>
    <li><input class="allday" type="checkbox" name="availableday[Tuesday][9-12]" value="9AM - 12AM"></li>
    <li><input class="allday" type="checkbox" name="availableday[Tuesday][12-6]" value="12PM - 6PM"></li>
    <li><input class="allday" type="checkbox" name="availableday[Tuesday][6-9]" value="6PM - 9PM"></li>
</div>
<div id="wed">
    <li><?php echo $this->__("WED");?> </li>
    <li><input class="allday" type="checkbox" name="availableday[Wednesday][9-12]" value="9AM - 12AM"></li>
    <li><input class="allday" type="checkbox" name="availableday[Wednesday][12-6]" value="12PM - 6PM"></li>
    <li><input class="allday" type="checkbox" name="availableday[Wednesday][6-9]" value="6PM - 9PM"></li>
</div>
```

How to validate at least one checkbox is checked?

Comment: You want to validate on client site (javascript) or backend f.e. with PHP?

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: your markup needs to be corrected... `li` (listitem) is a child of `ul` (unordered list) or `ol` (ordered list)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something along the following lines:

```
var formNodes  = document.checks.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (var i=0;i<formNodes.length;i++) {
   /* If one is true set a variable to true and exit the loop */
}
```

Stack overflow post [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534657/javascript-and-only-one-checkbox-undefined)

Cheers,

Truez

Comment: you need to correct this answer.. `checks`.. refers to the name of the form.. document.form['checks'] would be the equivalent.. also, `getElementsByTag('input')` would return all input tags.. you should at least add in the conditional statement on the input type..

Comment: Would this loop all input controls or just checkboxes? Just wondering if at any point another control could evaluate to true.

Comment: @grdev76 it would loop all input controls - in a form named checks - regardless of their type. 
the checked property is defined on the input tag, which is normalized.. http://jsfiddle.net/2r533gb1/ jsFiddle

Comment: @grdev76, with that said.. only the input types radio and checkbox display the checked value, update the control when the value is changed, and provide a means (click event) to alter the checked property. consider the different between `input:checked` and `input[checked="true"]`, the ladder is looking for the existence of an attribute. thus, CssSelectors (for querySelector or styling) won't work if you're toggling/assigning the checked property's value unless you're also creating/modifing the attributeNode on the DOM.

Comment: What is `document.checks`? If it is what @BrettCaswell hints above (the form itself which has id "checks"), then this is one of the worst things that can appear in a StackOverflow answer. Accessing DOM elements using their id as a property name is practice discouraged for long time; and afaict authors of DOM see it as one of their big mistakes. It works only for backward compatibility, but NEVER, EVER should it be used in any new code. There is `document.getElementById('checks')` or other APIs for that. -1 and if I could, I add -100, until this is fixed.

Answer (score 9):

Well, straightforwardly:

```
var isSomeAlldayCheckboxChecked = document
  .querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"].allday')
  .some(function (each) { return each.checked; });
```

Comment: The original (`'input.allday'`) was good enough, the only `<input>`s with class `allday` were checkboxes. There is no point to making selectors unnecessarily detailed. If you wanted to restrict the selector to checkboxes @BrettCaswell, you should have also renamed the variable to `isSomeAlldayCheckboxesChecked`.

Comment: The poster of the question you're answering stated "i want to check atleast one checkbox is checked".. that is a type constraint that you shouldn't ignore in your solution because you inferred - from the **sample code** - that it wasn't necessary.. in that regard, (`'.allday'`)  or (`'input'`) would have sufficed as well..

Comment: ... and you still left the variable name inconsistent with your change of the selector.

Comment: herby, as far as I'm concerned the variable would just be named foobar or result here.. I use the more qualified naming to function names.. in which case, it wouldn't be all that different to your suggested variable renaming here.. but it all depends on the scope..

Comment: Neverthless, it _was_ named contextually to name what it actually contains. When you changed implementation, you should have also renamed the variable, to match your change. Would you be so kind as to finish your edit properly? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
var count= 0;
var value_array=new Array();
jQuery('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(){ 
   value_array.push(jQuery(this).val());
   count = count + 1;
});

// count&value_array will tell you total selected
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a [supported browser](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3), you can leverage the :checked pseudo selector for a really succinct check. Simply do something like this:

```
if(document.forms[0].querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length) {
  //At least 1 checkbox is selected within document
}
```

Be sure to target the correct form, either through `document.querySelector` or the `document.forms` list on the document object (as seen above).

Answer (score 2):

You can use Jquery for this.

```
if ($('#form_id :checkbox:checked').length > 0)
{
        // one or more checkboxes are checked
}
else
{
       // no checkboxes are checked
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@`herby`'s  answer is the correct answer for checking whether some input in the `input[type='checkbox']` array is checked.

---

This answer returns an array of checked inputs using **querySelectorAll** (`MyFormManager.get_checkedInputs`); it demonstrates adding event listeners to the queries `input` elements `change` event (`MyFormManager.init`) - which appends the check state to the `className` of the element (`MyFormManager.onCheckChanged`) - to facilitate the process.

```js
var MyFormManager = {
  checkboxes: null,  
  onCheckChanged: function(sender, e) {
    console.log("sender:= %o, e:= %o", sender, e);
    sender.className = sender.className.replace(' true','').replace(' false','');
    sender.className += ' ' + String(sender.checked);
  },
  init : function() {
    checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");
    for (var i = 0, max = checkboxes.length; i < max; i++)
    {
      checkboxes[i].addEventListener('change', MyFormManager.onCheckChanged.bind(null, checkboxes[i]));
    }
  },
  get_checkedInputs : function() {
    return document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox'].true");
  }
}

console.log(MyFormManager);
    
MyFormManager.init();

var message = document.querySelector("div#message");
    
document.querySelector("button#runCheck").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  var checkedInputs = MyFormManager.get_checkedInputs();
  console.log(checkedInputs);
  message.innerHTML = "";
  var parentId;
  for (var i = 0, max = checkedInputs.length; i < max; i++)
  {
    parentId = checkedInputs[i].parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.id;
    message.innerHTML += '<div class="item"><span class="parentId">' + parentId + '</span><span class="checkedInput">' + checkedInputs[i].value + '</span></div>';
  }
});
```

```css
body {background-color:whitesmoke;}

div { display:block;}

div > ul { 
  list-style:none;
  margin:0.5em auto 0 auto;
  padding:0.27em;
  background-color:white;
  border:0.05cm solid silver;
}

input[type='checkbox'] {cursor:pointer;}

div:first-child > ul:first-child {margin-top:0em;}

div > ul > li {list-style:none;}

div > ul > li > label {display:inline-block;padding:0.1em 0.3em;margin:0;width:8em;text-align:right;}


div.item {display:block;}
div.item > span.parentId {display:inline-block;width:3em;text-transform:uppercase;}
div.item > span.checkedInput {display:inline-block;width:8em;text-align:right;}
```

```html
<div id="debugger">
  <div id='message'></div>
  <button id='runCheck'>Run Check</button>
</div>

<div id="sun">
  <ul>
    <li><!-- <?php echo $this->__("SUN");?> --></li>
    <li>
      <label>9AM - 12PM</label>
      <input class="allday" type="checkbox" name="availableday[Sunday][9-12]" value="9AM - 12PM">
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>12PM - 6PM</label>
      <input class="allday" type="checkbox" name="availableday[Sunday][12-6]" value="12PM - 6PM">
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>6PM - 9PM</label>
      <input class="allday" type="checkbox" name="availableday[Sunday][6-9]" value="6PM - 9PM">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="mon">
  <ul>
    <li><!-- <?php echo $this->__("MON");?> --></li>
    <li>
      <label>9AM - 12PM</label>
      <input class="allday" type="checkbox" name="availableday[Monday][9-12]" value="9AM - 12PM">
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>12PM - 6PM</label>
      <input class="allday" type="checkbox" name="availableday[Monday][12-6]" value="12PM - 6PM">
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>6PM - 9PM</label>
      <input class="allday" type="checkbox" name="availableday[Monday][6-9]" value="6PM - 9PM">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="tue">
  <ul>
    <li><!-- <?php echo $this->__("TUE");?> --></li>
    <li>
      <label>9AM - 12PM</label>
      <input class="allday" type="checkbox" name="availableday[Tuesday][9-12]" value="9AM - 12PM">
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>12PM - 6PM</label>
      <input class="allday" type="checkbox" name="availableday[Tuesday][12-6]" value="12PM - 6PM">
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>6PM - 9PM</label>
      <input class="allday" type="checkbox" name="availableday[Tuesday][6-9]" value="6PM - 9PM">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="wed">
  <ul>
    <li><!-- <?php echo $this->__("WED");?> --></li>
    <li>
      <label>9AM - 12PM</label>
      <input class="allday" type="checkbox" name="availableday[Wednesday][9-12]" value="9AM - 12PM">
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>12PM - 6PM</label>
      <input class="allday" type="checkbox" name="availableday[Wednesday][12-6]" value="12PM - 6PM">
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>6PM - 9PM</label>
      <input class="allday" type="checkbox" name="availableday[Wednesday][6-9]" value="6PM - 9PM">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="thur">
  <ul>
    <li><!-- <?php echo $this->__("THUR");?> --></li>
    <li>
      <label>9AM - 12PM</label>
      <input class="allday" type="checkbox" name="availableday[Thursday][9-12]" value="9AM - 12PM">
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>12PM - 6PM</label>
      <input class="allday" type="checkbox" name="availableday[Thursday][12-6]" value="12PM - 6PM">
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>6PM - 9PM</label>
      <input class="allday" type="checkbox" name="availableday[Thursday][6-9]" value="6PM - 9PM">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="fri">
  <ul>
    <li><!-- <?php echo $this->__("FRI");?> --></li>
    <li>
      <label>9AM - 12PM</label>
      <input class="allday" type="checkbox" name="availableday[Friday][9-12]" value="9AM - 12PM">
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>12PM - 6PM</label>
      <input class="allday" type="checkbox" name="availableday[Friday][12-6]" value="12PM - 6PM">
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>6PM - 9PM</label>
      <input class="allday" type="checkbox" name="availableday[Friday][6-9]" value="6PM - 9PM">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="sat">
  <ul>
    <li><!-- <?php echo $this->__("SAT");?> --></li>
    <li>
      <label>9AM - 12PM</label>
      <input class="allday" type="checkbox" name="availableday[Saturday][9-12]" value="9AM - 12PM">
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>12PM - 6PM</label>
      <input class="allday" type="checkbox" name="availableday[Saturday][12-6]" value="12PM - 6PM">
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>6PM - 9PM</label>
      <input class="allday" type="checkbox" name="availableday[Saturday][6-9]" value="6PM - 9PM">
    </li>
  </ul>  
</div>
```

---

note that this is not optimized, also it does not account for dynamic controls (postback or xhr);

Comment: note that this example 'walks' the DOM in the debug message functionality to determine the context of the checked day of the week... I would probably define and use data attributes on the input, instead of relying on a particular node structure - ..